# Add Dynamic ArrayList to ArrayAdapter and display on screen

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am having a hard time populating my ListView with dynamic items from my ArrayList and displaying them on the screen.

I have 2 xml files:
This is the activity file I want to populate my ListView with.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/activity_local_reps"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="airbornegamer.com.grgr4.ActivityLocalReps">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

And my xml file I want to use to add an image/text to the listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/unknown_representative" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Itemname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
```

In my file ActivityLocalReps.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_reps);
    //setting up data and populating repData.
    DisplayData(repData);
}    

public void DisplayData(LocalRepData repData){    
    allRepData = repData.queryAllNeededRepData();
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylist, R.id.Itemname, allRepData);
}
```

My allRepData has multiple elements in it, however the adapter does not seem to hook up the data to my listView.  Any help would be great, thanks!

**Edit 1

```
public class LocalRepData {

Context mContext;

public LocalRepData(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}    
//other methods and stuff........
}
```

I'm using this class mostly for data retrieval, so currently I'm not extending anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `LocalRepData` is a class you created that contains info then I would say it is fine.

What you want to understand it seems is the relationship between a `ListView` and it's Adapter. So you build up a `List<LocalRepData> theList;`. Then you want to create a Custom Adapter for your `ListView`, so extend `BaseAdapter` and when you are instantiating the Adapter, you would want to pass in your list of `LocalRepData`. Inside your `BaseAdapter` you will grab each item from the List and grab its image and string, then attach them to your 2nd xml, and finally inflate the view, by returning it. So I will show you an example here of what I mean.

I create my own simple `BaseAdapter`, and use just a standard `ListView`. I use a container class with my items called `WeatherLocation`. `WeatherLocation` is just a class that stores the local weather of an area (weather, zipcode, description of the weather when it was parsed, etc...). What I will do is build up a `List<WeatherLocations> weatherLocations`, then pass it into my adapter. Once the adapter is instantiated it will grab each `WeatherLocation` (depending on the row being displayed) and inflate it.

```
List<WeatherLocation> savedList = dbHelper.getAllWeatherLocations();
    //savedList.add(new WeatherLocation(72, "04005", "Biddeford"));
    if(savedList.size() > 0){
        mWeatherLocationAdapter = new WeatherLocationAdapter(savedList, this, R.layout.view_weather_location);
        lvLocations.setAdapter(mWeatherLocationAdapter);
    }
```

You can see above that I build up my List of `WeatherLocation`s and throw them, with my custom xml that I will be inflating for each view in the listview into my adapter when i instantiate it. Below is my custom adapter, only really 3 methods you care about, getCount, getItem, and getView(). GetCount and getView are the ones you absolutely have to focus on.

```
public class WeatherLocationAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private List <WeatherLocation> mLocations;
private Context mContext;
private int rowForLocationToInflate;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private SettingsManager mSettingsMananger;

public WeatherLocationAdapter(List<WeatherLocation> mLocations, Context mContext, int rowForLocationToInflate) {
    this.mLocations = mLocations;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.rowForLocationToInflate = rowForLocationToInflate;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // to grab the saved zipcode (selected zipcode)
    mSettingsMananger = new SettingsManager(mContext);
}

private void addLocation(WeatherLocation newLocation){
    mLocations.add(newLocation);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mLocations.size();
}

@Override
public WeatherLocation getItem(int position) {
    return mLocations.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //TODO build a viewholder

        // Inflate up
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowForLocationToInflate, parent, false);

        // Link up
        TextView tvZipcode = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvZipCode);
        TextView tvCity = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
        TextView tvTemp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDegree);

        // we will do logic here to pick the image
        TextView tvDesc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        TextView tvTime = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeStamp);
        ImageView ivWeather  =  (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivWeather);
        TextView tvSelected = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvCurrentlySelected);

        tvZipcode.setText(mLocations.get(position).getZipcode());
        tvCity.setText(mLocations.get(position).getCity());
        tvTemp.setText(String.valueOf(mLocations.get(position).getTemperature()));
        tvDesc.setText(mLocations.get(position).getDesc());

        // whats currently selected.
        if(mSettingsMananger.getZipCode().equals(mLocations.get(position).getZipcode())){
            tvSelected.setText("Currently Selected");
        }

        // Format the saved time.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(mLocations.get(position).getTime_stamp());
        String time = checkForMilitaryTime(cal.getTime().getHours(), cal.getTime().getMinutes());
        tvTime.setText(time);

        // Decide what image to display - based off the description we got back.
        String desc = mLocations.get(position).getDesc();
        if(desc.equals("sky is clear")){
            ivWeather.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_sun));
        }
        else if(desc.equals("few clouds")){
            ivWeather.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_cloudy));
        }
        else if(desc.equals("broken clouds")){
            ivWeather.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_cloudy));
        }
        else if(desc.equals("light intensity shower rain")){
            ivWeather.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_rain));
        }



        return rowView;
}
```

You can see in the `getView()` thats where all the work happens, everytime a item on a listview is displayed, `getview()` needs to inflate that view. So you can see that each view in that XML is being grabbed and I am attaching my Strings to their respected items.

Comment: Thank Daedalus, I am going to try to implement this following your example soon.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Daedalus, with your help and following this tutorial: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter I was able to make magic happen, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
 adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mylist, R.id.Itemname, allRepData);
```

Use Custom ArrayAdapter of your LocalRepData Type and implement getView() method and other methods as needed for custom adapters. That will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have an issue implementing this with my other class, which is mostly used for data retrieval.  I edited my question above.  I don't see how they tie together yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a custom adapter, you inflate the item in the adapters getview. Where you would attach the data to the 2nd xml your showing. So you got a list of LocalRepData and each localrepdata has a string and image. Tie them in the getView method of the adapter. 
Your oncreate doesnt show you building up your repData. Got to make sure its noy empty.

Comment: repData is populated with another call I'm not showing above.  It comes back with a list of 5 string items.  Currently I don't have a custom adapter in LocalRepData.  Since I'm doing a bunch of API calls in there it seems I may need to move that logic into another supporting class and extend LocalRepData and use getView there.  Dose that seem right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use multiple widgets in your listview's listitems such as EditText and ImageView, then you have to extend using ArrayAdapter and populate them in the getView() method.